# Robotium: verify that activity gets finished and the underlying one restored when "home" button clicked

Tags: android, testing, tdd, robotium

I' m using Android annotations and I have the following code in my Activity:

```
@OptionsItem
void homeSelected() {
    finish();
}
```

obviously, this code should finish the current activity, when the user has clicked the home button in ActionBar. But how can I test this code? I would like to be able to verify somehow that after clicking on the home button the current activity finished, and the previous activity restored. Is this possible? Or at least can I verify that my `homeSelected` method gets called after clicking the home button?

I'm using Robotium and I have the following test method:

```
@SmallTest
public void testGoBack() {
    solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton();
    // ???? How do I verify the homeSelected method was actually called?
}
```

Comment: did you tried adding toast to it ?

Comment: Can we remove the android-annotations flag? This is not related to AndroidAnnotations, since the question would be quite the same if you would not use AA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `waitForActivity(...)`.

```
waitForActivity(Class<? extends android.app.Activity> activityClass)
```

> Waits for an Activity matching the specified class.

Check out the [documentation](http://robotium.googlecode.com/svn/doc/index.html).

```
@SmallTest
public void testGoBack() {
    solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton();

    solo.waitForActivity(com.example.UpActivity.class);
}
```

The default routine uses a 20 seconds timeout.

p.s.: alternatively add a debug log to the `onDestroy()` method of your activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    ...
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        Log.d ("TAG", "Finishing MyActivity");
    }
}
```

and wait for this log message inside of your test method:

```
waitForLogMessage("Finishing MyActivity");
```

Comment: it didn't work for me. I got: expected:<...m.example.d.testing.[UpActivity]Activity_> but was:<...m.example.d.testing.[Current]Activity_>

Comment: @netimen: I'm not sure which activity you expected. Usually you can wait for any activity in your app - just provide the matching class. May be you can add relevant code above. Alternatively, you could try to work around any issues by waiting for a log message - see update above.